# Count of records in databind TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, treeview

i got simple TreeView bind through XmlDataSource . These data represents category which content certain items. And i need to show count of records in these categories. How can i do that? I got this code:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" 
        runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
        ImageSet="Arrows"
        ExpandDepth="1" 
        OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="root" TextField="name" ValueField="id"  />
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="category" TextField="name" ValueField="id" />
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="subcategory" TextField="name" ValueField="id" />
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="subsubcategory" TextField="name" ValueField="id" />
        </DataBindings>
        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" 
            Font-Size="10pt" 
            ForeColor="Black" 
            HorizontalPadding="5px"
            NodeSpacing="0px" 
            VerticalPadding="0px" />
        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" 
            ForeColor="#5555DD" 
            HorizontalPadding="0px"
            VerticalPadding="0px" />
    </asp:TreeView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Categories.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Should I call some Sql command from this page or maybe from XmlDataSource?. Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would proceed to display the numbre of children appended to the name, using a TreeNodeDataBound event handler and an XPathNavigator

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
    XmlElement myElement = (XmlElement)e.Node.DataItem;
    // e.Node.NavigateUrl = ...
    // e.Node.Expanded = ...
    e.Node.Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})"
                   ,myElement.Attributes["name"].Value
                   ,myElement.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(./child::*)"));
}
```

Hope this will help